# Phalcon php pass parameter in constructor

Tags: php, phalcon

I would like to pass parameter to constructor in controller. Is it possible to do ?

I am trying to pass interface defination in constructor.

or is it possible to bind or set constructor in DI ?

below is my code.

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Repositories\IUsersRepository;

class UsersController extends ControllerBase
{
    private  $users;

    public function __construct(IUsersRepository $usersRepository)
    {
        $this->users = $usersRepository;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed by using below code in service.php

```
$di->set('usersRepository', array(
    'className' => 'Phalcon\Repositories\UsersRepository'
));

$di->set('UsersController', array(
    'className' => 'UsersController',
    'arguments' => array(
        array('type' => 'service', 'name' => 'usersRepository')
    )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.. take a look...

```
http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#instantiating-classes-via-the-service-container
```

If you want to send data on every request use `dispatch Service`

```
$di->set('IndexController', function() {
    $component = new Component();
    $component->private_method();
    return $component;
}, true);
```

I wonder y u need this method!

Comment: I would like to use repository pattern in phalcon. So trying to pass repository definition in constructor